# docker arg misssing in multi-stage builds

Tags: docker, dockerfile

ARG `BUILD_DIR` missng after second `FROM`.
What I doing wrong?

Dockerfile:

```
# build
# одноразовый контейнер
FROM node:latest as build

ARG BUILD_DIR=/build
# создание директории приложения
WORKDIR $BUILD_DIR

# установка зависимостей
# символ астериск ("*") используется для того чтобы по возможности
# скопировать оба файла: package.json и package-lock.json
COPY package*.json \
    tsconfig.json \
    ./

COPY src src

RUN echo ${BUILD_DIR}

RUN npm i
RUN npm run build

# ---------------------------------------
# build end
#
# app
# ---------------------------------------
RUN echo "1\n"; test -n "$BUILD_DIR" || (echo "BUILD_DIR  not set" && false)
FROM node:14-alpine as production
RUN echo "2\n"; test -n "$BUILD_DIR" || (echo "BUILD_DIR  not set" && false)
ARG PM2_CONFIG=out/config/ecosystem.config.js

#RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
#    build-essential

RUN npm i -g pm2

# создание директории приложения
WORKDIR /usr/local/app

RUN echo ${BUILD_DIR}

COPY --from=build /build/out out
COPY --from=build /build/node_modules node_modules

#EXPOSE # бот использует поллинг

CMD pm2 start ${PM2_CONFIG} && pm2 logs
```

Part of output is

```sh
Step 9/18 : RUN echo "1\n"; test -n "$BUILD_DIR" || (echo "BUILD_DIR  not set" && false)
 ---> Running in c7b0a92fc970
1

Removing intermediate container c7b0a92fc970
 ---> 977a5ec0be6f
Step 10/18 : FROM node:14-alpine as production
 ---> 87c43f8d8077
Step 11/18 : RUN echo "2\n"; test -n "$BUILD_DIR" || (echo "BUILD_DIR  not set" && false)
 ---> Running in e2b3de94bb3a
2\n
BUILD_DIR  not set
The command '/bin/sh -c echo "2\n"; test -n "$BUILD_DIR" || (echo "BUILD_DIR  not set" && false)' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

docker version: `19.03.8`

Comment: You're in fact missing `ARG BUILD_DIR` after the second `FROM`; it needs to be repeated in each build stage that uses it.  I wouldn't parameterize this (especially because it only controls a path that doesn't exist outside the build stage); just hard-code `/build` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
ARG BUILD_DIR=/build

# build
# одноразовый контейнер
FROM node:14 as build

ARG BUILD_DIR
```

There is [global and local scope](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact)
Global can be translated into local of each container